# Can't open a wordpress site in a iframe

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, webserver

Im trying to open a wordpres site in a  iframe. My problem it is just blank with no content. Im trying that cuz the link is too ugly to use. I can't reirect it from my homepage because i have different domain names here and would get an ssl error.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>seyo-IV Blog</title>
  <meta name="description" content="MyBlog">
  <meta name="author" content="Sergiy Ivanov">



</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="https://ui-6a306dcfd1868391240de49d4a3962d7.seyo-iv.sandcats.io" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forget it im using the wrong link....